# Using application's Log4J configuration under JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j, jboss7.x

I'm am having trouble logging using my appenders defined on my XML log4j configuration file.

I created the **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** on my EAR's META-INF folder with no sucess.

The **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** structure is:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" slot="main"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I have even tried to edit my **standalone.conf.bat** file adding the following line:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false"
```

My application deployment is like this:

```
-> MyAppEAR.ear
   -> META-INF
      -> MANIFEST.MF
   -> MyAoo.war
      -> META-INF
         -> MANIFEST.MF
         -> jboss-deployment-structure.xml
      -> WEB-INF
         -> web.xml
         -> lib
            -> log4j-1.2.17.jar
            -> ---
         -> classes
            -> log4j.xml
            -> ...
```

I've noticed the following error:

- **jboss-deployment-structure.xml in subdeployment ignored. jboss-deployment-structure.xml is only parsed for top level deployments.**

I even tried migrating from JBOSS 7.1.0 to 7.1.1

Some help please!

Thanks

---

Thanks for the repply James.

I did what you said and moved the **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** file to **MyAppEAR.ear/META-INF**.

I've noticed that this way the exception:

```
jboss-deployment-structure.xml in subdeployment ignored. jboss-deployment-structure.xml is only parsed for top level deployments.
```

... doesn't occur. I don't know if that means that the file was parsed... how can I tell?

Despite of this new behaviour my **log4j.xml** configuration file still isn't loaded and the logger used still is Log4J's.

I know this becaused I wrote to the console:

```
System.out.println(Logger.getRootLogger().getClass().toString())
```

...and got:

```
class org.jboss.logmanager.log4j.BridgeLogger
```

I've also tried:

- moving my **log4j.xml** to **MyAppEAR.ear/META-INF**.
- removing the unecessary **-Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false** from **standalone.conf.bat**
- removing **slot** from my **jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

Any more ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi RedEagle see the following configuration which i have tested and its working fine...
**Step-1** 
 Create a new module as

jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/com/company/mylog/main/

```
                          -module.xml
                          -log4j-1.2.14.jar

Content of  module.xml


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.company.mylog">
    <resources>
      <resource-root path="log4j-1.2.14.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="javax.api"/>
         </dependencies>
      </module>
```

**Step-2**
Now IN my.ear/META-INF/

```
          -jboss-deployment-structure.xml
          -MANIFEST.MF
```

content of jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
 <jboss-deployment-structure>
              <deployment>

                  <exclusions>
                  <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
                  </exclusions>

              </deployment>


              <sub-deployment name="MyWeb.war">
                    <exclusions>
                    <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
                    </exclusions>
              </sub-deployment>

              <sub-deployment name="MyBeans.jar">
                <exclusions>
                  <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
                </exclusions>
              </sub-deployment>


              </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Content of MANIFEST.MF

```
        Manifest-Version: 1.0
        Dependencies: com.company.mylog
```

**Step-3**
 Content of MyLogger.java

```
public static Logger getLogger(String name) {

    Logger  logger= LogManager.getLogger(name);
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties"); //Path to log4j.properties as many option available in my case for testing i used static path /home/gyani/log4j.properties
    return logger;
}
```

**Step-4**
Here is log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=info,gyani
log4j.appender.gyani=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.gyani.File=/home/gyani/myserverlog.log
log4j.appender.gyani.Append=true
log4j.appender.gyani.MaxFileSize=100000KB
log4j.appender.gyani.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.gyani.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.gyani.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy}] [%-5p] [%c]: %m%n
```

Comment: Thanks gYanl! That worked! I didn't even need to to all those steps. All I did was create the jboss-deployment-structure.xml on the EAR's META-INF folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` needs to be in your `MyAppEAR.ear/META-INF` directory. There is also no need for the `slot` attribute for this case.

Also the `-Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false` isn't used in JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final, but it doesn't hurt anything either.

Comment: Hello James. Any more ideas? Thanks

Comment: Try moving the log4j library to MyAppEAR.ear/lib.

Comment: Could you maybe post your log4j configuration file?